# Fragment onBackPressed how to used back first Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

**I'm going back to the first fragment here but I'm having an error defining currentfragment**

**class Fragment declare**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
```

**onCreateView**

```
 fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            List<Fragment> f = fragmentManager.getFragments();
            Fragment frag = f.get(0);
            currentFragment = frag.getClass().getSimpleName();  // here error how to delcare currentFragment  ???
        }
    });
```

**onBackPressed**

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        switch (currentFragment) { // here error how to delcare currentFragment  ???
            case "FragmentOne":
                // your code here
                return;
            case "FragmentTwo":
                // your code here
                return;
            default:
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                // default action for any other fragment (return to previous)
        }}
```

Comment: You should not be doing this at all. Did you read the [documentation for having an individual fragment intercept back directly](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back)?